# Error cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<GameLibrary.Cards.Card>' to 'GameLibrary.Cards.Card'

Tags: c#

```
   private List<List<Card>> GetCardMatchesInHand()
    {
        List<Card> list4;
        List<List<Card>> list = new List<List<Card>>();
        List<GameLibrary.Cards.Card> list2 = new List<GameLibrary.Cards.Card>()
        List<Card> list3 = new List<Card>();
        list4 = new List<Card> {
            list2,
            list3,
            list4
        };
        List<Card> list5 = this.Cards.ToList<Card>();
        using (List<Card>.Enumerator enumerator = this.Cards.GetEnumerator())
        {
            Predicate<Card> match = null;
            Predicate<Card> predicate2 = null;
            Predicate<Card> predicate3 = null;
            Predicate<Card> predicate4 = null;
            Predicate<Card> predicate5 = null;
            Card c;
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                c = enumerator.Current;
                list5.Remove(c);
                if (match == null)
                {
                    match = element => element.CardValue == c.CardValue;
                }
                Card item = list5.Find(match);
                if (item != null)
                {
                    if (predicate2 == null)
                    {
                        predicate2 = element => element.CardValue == c.CardValue;
                    }
                    if (list2.Exists(predicate2))
                    {
                        if (predicate3 == null)
                        {
                            predicate3 = element => element.CardValue == c.CardValue;
                        }
                        item = list2.Find(predicate3);
                        list2.Remove(item);
                        list3.Add(c);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (predicate4 == null)
                        {
                            predicate4 = element => element.CardValue == c.CardValue;
                        }
                        if (list3.Exists(predicate4))
                        {
                            if (predicate5 == null)
                            {
                                predicate5 = element => element.CardValue == c.CardValue;
                            }
                            item = list3.Find(predicate5);
                            list3.Remove(item);
                            list4.Add(c);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            list2.Add(c);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

I'm getting said error on this line "list2, list3, list4". Now Why am I getting this error? This is the entire code posted now. 
Maybe now you can see what im trying to do.
Also using this to check for match in the list.

```
    List<List<Card>> cardMatches = this.GetCardMatchesInHand();
```

Comment: Can you explain what you try to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

It's trying to do the equivalent of:

```
List<Card> tmp = new List<Card>();
tmp.Add(list2);
tmp.Add(list3);
tmp.Add(list4);
List<Card> list4 = tmp;
```

Now you can't call `Add` with a *list* of the element type - which is why you're getting that error. You're *also* trying to use `list4` when assigning a value to `list4` for the first time.

It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, but if you want `list4` to be all the elements of `list2` and `list3`, you can use:

```
List<Card> list4 = list2.Concat(list3).ToList();
```

Or if you really wanted `list4` to be a list of lists, you need to declare it that way and call the appropriate constructor:

```
// Note not using list4 within the initializer...
List<List<Card>> list4 = new List<List<Card>> { list2, list3 };
```

Your whole metho looks a little confused at the moment - you're not using the `list` variable at all, and you're declaring `list4` much earlier than you use it. Neither of these is an error, but both are a little odd.