# UPDATED Error cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<GameLibrary.Cards.Card>' to 'GameLibrary.Cards.Card'

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<GameLibrary.Cards.Card>' to 'GameLibrary.Cards.Card'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065481/error-cannot-convert-from-system-collections-generic-listgamelibrary-cards-car)

```
  private List<List<Card>> GetCardMatchesInHand()
    {
        List<Card> list4;
        List<List<Card>> list = new List<List<Card>>();
        List<GameLibrary.Cards.Card> list2 = new List<GameLibrary.Cards.Card>()
        List<Card> list3 = new List<Card>();
        list4 = new List<Card> {
            list2,
            list3,
            list4
        };
        List<Card> list5 = this.Cards.ToList<Card>();
        using (List<Card>.Enumerator enumerator = this.Cards.GetEnumerator())
        {
            Predicate<Card> match = null;
            Predicate<Card> predicate2 = null;
            Predicate<Card> predicate3 = null;
            Predicate<Card> predicate4 = null;
            Predicate<Card> predicate5 = null;
            Card c;
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                c = enumerator.Current;
                list5.Remove(c);
                if (match == null)
                {
                    match = element => element.CardValue == c.CardValue;
                }
                Card item = list5.Find(match);
                if (item != null)
                {
                    if (predicate2 == null)
                    {
                        predicate2 = element => element.CardValue == c.CardValue;
                    }
                    if (list2.Exists(predicate2))
                    {
                        if (predicate3 == null)
                        {
                            predicate3 = element => element.CardValue == c.CardValue;
                        }
                        item = list2.Find(predicate3);
                        list2.Remove(item);
                        list3.Add(c);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (predicate4 == null)
                        {
                            predicate4 = element => element.CardValue == c.CardValue;
                        }
                        if (list3.Exists(predicate4))
                        {
                            if (predicate5 == null)
                            {
                                predicate5 = element => element.CardValue == c.CardValue;
                            }
                            item = list3.Find(predicate5);
                            list3.Remove(item);
                            list4.Add(c);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            list2.Add(c);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

I'm getting said error on this line "list2, list3, list4". Now Why am I getting this error? This is the entire code posted now. 
Maybe now you can see what im trying to do.
Also using this to check for match in the list.

```
    List<List<Card>> cardMatches = this.GetCardMatchesInHand();
```

Comment: Just posting the complete code still doesn't explain what you're trying to do. All the previous comments on your previous question still apply.

Comment: Do not repost your question just because it is updated. Update your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
list4 = new List<Card> {
```

to

```
list1 = new List<List<Card>> {
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables `list2`, `list3` and `list4` holds lists of cards, so you can't make a list of cards that contain them. They are lists of cards, not cards.

A list to hold them would be a list of lists of cards:

```
list4 = new List<List<Card>> {
  list2,
  list3,
  list4
};
```